# Calling bash script inside the Perl Script with system command"

Tags: perl, bash, ssh

I have a basic shell script like this;

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Openning ssh connection to remote host "$2" for "$1" user and finding the archive directory "$3""
ssh "$1"@"$2" find "$3"
```

I have another perl script named with Archive.pl in that script we are connecting remote server with Telnet connection. I want to call my script inside this Perl script to use other modules of Perl script. I'm trying that command but it doesn't work.

```
system("Connector.sh",$arg1,$arg2,$arg3);
```

Any ideas to do that ?

Comment: Are you sure of the path??

Comment: Perl and bash script is at the same path actually

Comment: I guess you need to mention - ./Connector.sh

Comment: I need to do it inside the Perl script. I'm not trying to work on the console "sh script.sh". Because in Perl script there are other modules which i wanted to work on.

Comment: Is it really valid to nest quotes like that? `echo "Opening ... "$2" for "$1" ...."$3""`?

Comment: Perhaps you should use something like [`Net::SSH`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3A%3ASSH) instead?

Comment: I can't import libraries to target or source host , i solved the connection problem shell script works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the shell script, and just put this in your Perl script.

```
print qq(Opening ssh connection to remote host "$arg2" for "$arg1" user and finding the archive directory "$arg3");
system("ssh", "$arg1\@$arg2", "find", $arg3)
```

Comment: ssh: picroot: temporary name resolution failure. I'm getting that error

Comment: What is `picroot`? Does the `ssh` connection work outside your Perl script?

Comment: picroot is username. Yes i can easily connect via console or my bash script.

Comment: See my edit; I forgot to switch to the correct variables for the call to `system`. Does that help?

Comment: What are the values of `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3`?

Comment: I'm reading these arguments from .csv file and this modules works fine i checked it. I can write these values into console but i can't use these values on this system command

Comment: You forgot to escape the `@` sign, so `@$arg2` was interpolated to the empty string, which made the ssh fail. Since you did not use warnings, you were not warned about this critical failure. Lesson is: always, always, always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: @TLP Thanks for the "\@"; that's an important fix.

Comment: @TLP in that example what will system command return ? Can i parse it to other variable ?

Comment: If you want to capture the output of the `ssh` command, use  `my $output = qx/ssh $arg1\@$arg2 find $arg3/` instead.

Comment: @Hayra `system` returns the exit value of the program it ran, not the standard output, as many people initially think. Like chepner says, if you want to capture output, use backticks or `qx()`. (`qx//` is the same thing, just using a different delimiter, something you can do with many Perl functions).

Comment: @chepner the qx function that you said doesn't work :/

Comment: @Hayra [It doesn't work](http://tlp-perl.blogspot.se/2013/06/its-not-working.html) is a bad way to describe a problem.

Comment: It gives no output when i parse it i think the syntax of qx must be different but I don't know which is correct

Comment: Well, you are saying several things there. 1) You run the qx and store the output in a variable, 2) you parse the output, 3) you check the result. 1 and 2 does not give any visible output, so you are saying that 3 is giving no output? Have you tried printing the raw output of qx with `Data::Dumper`?

Comment: Also, do you see any output of ssh on the screen? Differently from when you use the same command with `system`?

Comment: You can come to the chat room for quicker responses. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50132/tlp